# How can I add a clear button and how can I add a marks column?

Tags: vb.net, datatable

```
Public Class FRM_GPACalculator

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim j As Integer = 1
    Dim sumOfCreditHours As Double = 0
    Dim sumOfGPA As Double = 0

    Sub calculateGpa()
        sumOfCreditHours = 0
        sumOfGPA = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
            sumOfCreditHours = sumOfCreditHours + DGV_GpaCalculation.Rows(i).Cells("Credit Hours").Value
            sumOfGPA = sumOfGPA + DGV_GpaCalculation.Rows(i).Cells("GPA").Value
        Next
        LBL_TotalNumberOfSubjects.Text = j
        LBL_TotalCreditHour.Text = sumOfCreditHours
        LBL_TotalGPA.Text = sumOfGPA
        LBL_GPA.Text = sumOfGPA / sumOfCreditHours
    End Sub

    Private Sub BTN_ADD_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BTN_Add.Click
        Try
            Dim values() As Object = {j, TXT_SubjectName.Text.ToString(), CDbl(TXT_Grade.Text), CDbl(TXT_CreditHour.Text), CDbl(TXT_Grade.Text) * CDbl(TXT_CreditHour.Text)}
            dt.Rows.Add(values)
            DGV_GpaCalculation.DataSource = dt
            calculateGpa()
            j = j + 1
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub FRM_GPACalculator_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dt.Columns.Add("Index", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add("Subject Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add("Grade", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add("Credit Hours", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        dt.Columns.Add("GPA", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    End Sub

End Class
```

I created a GPA Calculator in VB.NET, as you can see the code as well!!

Here you have to enter your subject name, GPA, and credit hours and in a result it gives you total GPA, credit hours and CGPA!

Now how can I add a clear button that could clear everything?
and as we input GPA,Cridete Hours and Subject name  i add a text filed for iputing marks of the subject as well now how i can add Marks column in DataTable and how i could Calculate the persentage ?

plz help me I will be very thankful!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    dt.Rows.Clear()
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
 End Sub
```

EDIT didnt see the second part of your question. Could you clarify that part

Comment: and as we input GPA,Cridete Hours and Subject name i add a text filed for iputing marks of the subject as well now how i can add Marks column in DataTable and how i could Calculate the persentage ?